# Can't use resizebox with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htp]
%       \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
            \node at (0,0) {Me};
        \end{tikzpicture}
%       }
     
    \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code works, but if I remove the comments (so that `resizebox` becomes active) I get a lot of errors:

```
Improper \prevdepth. }
Missing \endgroup inserted. }
Missing \endgroup inserted. }
Missing } inserted. }
\begin{figure} on input line 8 ended by \end{tikzpicture}. }
Too many }'s. }
Package graphics Error: Division by 0. }
Extra \endgroup. }
\begin{document} ended by \end{figure}. \end{figure}
Extra \endgroup. \end{figure}
running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into your preamble.
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Even using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` there's an error.

What could it be wrong?

Comment: You might want to mention that it works fine when you use, say, `article` instead of `standalone`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `standalone` bundle doc (v1.3b – 2022/10/10),

- class option `tikz`

  > This option declares that the content contains of one or more `tikzpicture`
  > environments. This sets `multi=tikzpicture,varwidth=false` and loads the `tikz` package.
- class option `multi`

  > A set of environments which hold a single page must either be given as option value or declared using `\standaloneenv{<envname>, ...}`. No typeset material should be used outside such environments.

Therefor in OP's example it's the outer `\resizebox` that breaks the condition.

Removing class option `tikz` and (manually) loading `tikz` do the work. Also, floating environment `figure` is unnecessary here.

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \node at (0,0) {Me};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Note the two `%` added to remove the space characters converted from newlines.

Comment: Thanks, also for the clarification about the `%` characters, which I often encountered in the examples.

Comment: > "requires that tikzpicture is the outer most environment". It worked for me replacing `include`by `input`thanks to your comment I quoted